# I can't change connection and object when drag and drop from Main.storyboard to ViewController.swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode8

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ez8vV.png)

I can't change connection and object when drag and drop from Main.storyboard to ViewController.swift

I made a Google signIn system. So, I made a view for SignIn and set its custom class to .

And I drag and drop from Main.storyboard to ViewController.swift, But I can't change Connection and object.

Connection is fixed by 'Action' and Object is fixed by 'Exit'. I can't change.

Not only this time(this signin Button) but also every button or view.

how can i solve this problem?

I saw this reference and follow.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/google-signin

Comment: Wait a second: are you sure that what you selected is a button and not a view?

Comment: Yeah, Both Button and View, etc. can select only 'action(connection)' and 'exit(object)'. : ( I try it another(new) View Controller, but results is same.

Comment: No, you did NOT add a BUTTON. You added a VIEW instead. Delete from the storyboard what you think is a button and instead add a button (search for it in the bottom right corner of XCode). The "preview"-image in your `View Controller Scene` should then show a blue `B` instead of an empty white box (where it now says 'Sign In Button')

Comment: I just updated the answer below to resolve the problem into which you will probably run in a moment

Answer (score 2):

You added a `View` and not a `Button` to the ViewController. Fix that in the storyboard and try it again. (Search for 'Button' in the bottom right)

Oh, and what I just saw: You obviously didn't set the class of the whole View to `GIDSignInButton`, but only of the additional view you added. Select the white bar above the View you want to add the button to and then on the right go to the Identity Inspector (Or via `Cmd + Alt + 3`) and add `GIDSignInButton` there again.

Then you can start dragging from the button.
Or you write the `@IBOutlet var buttonOutlet: UIButton!` and

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        print("Button was pressed")
}
```

manually and connect if afterwards...

Answer (score 1):

First of all your have to make sure you are dragging to the same view controller class as in your storyboard. To do that you have to choose correct view controller class in storyboard in utility section. In utility section identity inspector choose correct view controller class

[image]

[image]
Than you'll be able to drag to your view controller with no problem.

Let me know if it worked.

Comment: You may find that an object (such as a button) can be dragged into your file as Action only, but Reference Outlet is not offered even when dragging into your Cocoa Touch Class file above the viewDidLoad (where Reference Outlet is pre-selected).  This is what happens when the ViewController in your Storyboard hasn't been connected to your file (as per Lavrin's answer above).